# sticky footer w/ side header

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

Hi i'm a new member here and also new in creating websites i want some help for my problem.

I'm searching about the sticky footer and i'm happy that i done it correctly but my problem appears when i'm change the height of my browser, it creating a space below my header. I want to ask some help to fix my problem. here's some screenshots of my website (i'm doing it thru localhost so i can't provide links (= ). I'm using wordpress

Screenshot of my problem when re-sizing the height [a link](http://i39.tinypic.com/2r74nds.jpg)

my HTML structure [a link](http://i41.tinypic.com/f3ci9d.jpg)

and here's my CSS stylesheet

```
html, body {height: 100%;}



#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:920px;
    }




#header {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    }




#main {
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px; 
    }




#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
    background:yellow;
        }
```

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are doing do to the lack of information but this may be able to help.
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: i'm sorry if i give a lack of information. I thought i already give all the information of my problem. I already try that method but my header having a white space when i adjust the height of my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this method. Worked for me...
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: i already try that method, if you can see my stylesheet it's almost the same. i don't use only the conditional styles. anyways thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

try giving css as

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
margin:auto;
width:100%!important;
```

for header to be sticky at top

Comment: thanks for the reply sir but i want my header beside w/ my main content like the screenshot above.